# mount remote mac file system on windows so its viewable in explorer

Tags: windows, mac, windows-explorer, mount

I work on a windows machine usually, but the files I work with are not. They used to be on a linux machine, so I was able to use sshfs to view the files in winodws explorer just fine. Now the files have been moved to a mac machine and sshfs doesnt seem to work. Is there another way I can achieve the same thing? perhaps another application that does the same but for macs?

Answer (score 2):

Your best (or at least most reliable) bet is going to be to share files on the Mac system via SMB. That's what Windows supports natively for file sharing. This set of instructions should help for setting it up on the Mac:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10777

After that, you'll be able to connect to the Mac from Windows via typing `\\<Mac's IP>` in the "Search programs and files" field in the Windows Start Menu.